# Same URL, different QR code - which is better?

Tags: qr-code, error-correction

I have used a few different online QR code generator sites to create static QR codes (I never do dynamic - I don't need any of their "features" and I don't want them tracking my visitors). Recently I noticed that depending on which site I use, the resulting code is a little different, and I'm curious why. I don't know how to analyze the underlying data, but I assume there is a difference in checksums or other error correction techniques. Is there a way to know which would be more reliably readable?

For example, using the URL "https://japan.deafmin.org", three sites rendered it as follows, all the same number of squares (unlike one other tool I tried, which used many more squares even though I declined all options - seems fishy!) but in a different pattern. The generators were (left to right) https://www.qr-code-generator.com, https://www.qrcode-monkey.com, and https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com. The first two sites are even owned by the same company, but their codes are still different.

[image]

Does anyone know what characteristics can change even though the code theoretically represents the exact same string of characters?

UPDATE: After learning a couple of clues, I'm even more mystified. Here are the two clues:

- According to https://www.qrcode-tiger.com/qr-code-error-correction, the error correction level (L, M, Q, or H) is indicated by the left-most data bit on the bottom row and the one above it.
- A comment under an answer here pointed me to https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx which gives the raw bits of the code.

But that makes me more confused. In theory, codes #1 and #3 in my examples use error correction level L (7%) while #2 uses M (15%). But here are the bytes as decoded by ZXing:

```
#1 qr-code-generator
71 a4 19 68 74 74 70 73   3a 2f 2f 6a 61 70 61 6e
2e 64 65 61 66 6d 69 6e   2e 6f 72 67 00 ec 11 ec
11 ec

#2 qr-code-monkey
41 96 87 47 47 07 33 a2   f2 f6 a6 17 06 16 e2 e6
46 56 16 66 d6 96 e2 e6   f7 26 70 ec

#3 the-qr-code-generator
41 96 87 47 47 07 33 a2   f2 f6 a6 17 06 16 e2 e6
46 56 16 66 d6 96 e2 e6   f7 26 70 ec 11 ec 11 ec
11 ec
```

#1 contains the exact bytes of the URL (`68 74 74 70 73 3A 2F 2F 6A 61 70 61 6E 2E 64 65 61 66 6D 69 6E 2E 6F 72 67`) with just a few bytes before and after. #2 and #3 are completely different from that, but similar to each other. One mystery is that although #2 supposedly has the most error correction, it has the fewest bytes - how can that be? And #2's entire data set is a subset of #3 (followed in #3 only by `11 ec 11 ec 11 ec`), so those are very similar, but yet the patterns of squares are completely different - huh?

Comment: I think the error correction has to do with the visual pattern itself. Remember, the whole idea of error correction here is to be able to recover from physical damage and not hex value damage. But it is all confusing.

Comment: Oh, I guess that could be so. I was assuming the fact that the bytes of #2 and #3 don't correlate directly to the bytes of the URL meant that error correction was already in there somehow (some sort of compression encoding with checksums). The conversion from bytes to squares already includes some SERIOUS compression - a 25x25 QR code contains 344 data squares (after you subtract the registration areas) - uncompressed, that would only describe 1.3 bytes! So I guess it is both confusing and magic!

Comment: Here, read up on error correction in QR codes at [this site](https://blog.qrstuff.com/general/qr-code-error-correction).

Comment: I've seen that page - the information is similar to the qrcode-tiger page on the same topic that I linked in my update. By the way, I made two calculation errors in my previous comment (can I claim to have had a senior moment?) - it's 452 data squares, not 344, and more importantly, a byte is 8 bits, not 256 (it's 256 discrete values, not bits). Duh - that makes WAY more sense!

Answer (score 2):

Sure, QR codes have error correcting data. Different levels of error correcting adds more or less data depending on the level. That's probably the reason. Obviously more error correcting can cause you to jump QR code size if the URL is long enough. So some sites scale the error correcting as it approaches the amount of data that can fit in that size QR code.

The next option is that QR codes support multiple char encodings. So it has to specify which encoding is used. Looking at the spec, ISO-8859-1 is the "default" but some newer docs say UTF-8 should be the default. As you have to indicate which encoding is happening that will change the QR code.

Here are some links with further reading:

https://4js.com/online_documentation/fjs-gst-2.50.02-manual-html/c_grd_barcodes_qr_code.html

https://www.qrcode.com/en/about/

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to determine which error correction level was used in a given QR code? That's likely to be the difference (unless one or two of them include an ECI code for no reason - it's definitely not needed for a simple, ASCII-only URL).

Comment: https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx This will give you the raw data which would allow you to work out what is going on. I don't know a lib or tool that just spits out the details of which error correction encoding is being used. But that's because ZXing makes it so that I've never needed to worry

Comment: The raw data is interesting, but I still don't know what I'm looking at. "...monkey" and "the-qr..." have the same first 28 bytes, plus "the-qr" adds `11ec11ec11ec` on the end. "qr-code-generator" is almost completely different from the others, but it's the only one that contains the URL in recognizable form - it has `71 a4 19`, then the URL, then `11 ec 11 ec`. I don't know what to conclude from this about which site makes the most robust but efficient code.

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned here that I edited my question - otherwise you might not see it. One thing you might find interesting is that I found how to tell what error correction level is used.